# MySQL Partitioning on event tables with start and end datetime columns

Tags: mysql, index, partitioning

I am curious as to what solutions are out there for partitioning tables that log events, that allow both efficient querying and the advantages of pruning when truncating data.

Suppose I have a simple table that records events from different locations:

```
tblEvents (
  event_id,
  location_id,
  start_datetime,
  end_datetime
)
```

Most queries on this table will take the form of:

```
SELECT    event_id
FROM      tblEvents
WHERE     location_id = @queried_location_id
AND       start_datetime < @queried_end_datetime
AND       end_datetime > @queried_start_datetime
```

To date, I have partitioned by the location_id, and simply just indexed the datetime columns. Performance-wise, this has sufficed, and I never planned to keep more than a couple of months worth of data in the database, so it seemed future-proof as well.

The problem arose when I actually went to purge data from this table (it is very large and also involved in replication). Using `DELETE FROM tblEvents WHERE start_datetime < @some_date` proved to be very slow, and created problems with requests being made from other clients (not surprisingly).

Partitioning by either of the datetime columns is no good. Although it solves my data purging problem, it makes the query above inefficient, as it still needs to look at multiple partitions depending on the dates being queried.

Am I missing a common solution here? Is there a more efficient way to purge my data? Or is there a smarter way to partition/index that I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the time ranges overlap for a given location?

If you need to delete *all* rows where `start_datetime < @some_date`, then the best way is via `PARTITIONing` based on `start_datetime`.  Use `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(start_datetime))` and base it on days or weeks or months, such that you have about 20-50 partitions.  See [*details*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).

**Plan A:**

Once you partition *that* way, then have the `PRIMARY KEY` be `(location_id, end_datetime, start_datetime)`, in *this* order.  If those 3 columns are not sufficient to be unique, and, say, you have `id AUTO_INCREMENT`, then do this:

```
PRIMARY KEY(location_id, end_datetime, start_datetime, id),
INDEX(id)
```

Now, let's analyze

```
WHERE     location_id = @queried_location_id
AND       start_datetime < @queried_end_datetime
AND       end_datetime > @queried_start_datetime
```

The following steps happen:

1. "partition pruning" based on `start_datetime`.  This may *or may not* help much, depending on how new the 'start' is.  On average(?), it will eliminate half the partitions (not much benefit).
2. Using the PK, it will home in on the appropriate `location_id` and the `end_datetime`.
3. Scan forward in the data (since the PK is 'clustered' with the data), checking the rest of those location_ids for a match.
4. Repeat for each partition not pruned out by step 1
5. Combine the results from the partition.

**Plan B:**

If your start..end ranges are predominately **recent** dates *and* if you can purge based on `end_datetime`, then this would probably be better because it would predominately focus on the last partition:

```
PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(end_datetime))

PRIMARY KEY(location_id, start_datetime, end_datetime, id),
INDEX(id)
```

*If* the ranges are not overlapping, then folding in [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges) may give significantly more performance.

But... If `end_datetime` is `NULL` initially, this will throw the row in to the "first" partition.  So... Be sure to have an extra partition at the beginning for that -- else the `DROP` for purging old records will toss them by mistake.  That is, have the first range be `VALUES LESS THAN (0)`. 
 Then have the second range be the oldest month (or week or whatever), and drop that for purging.

Another issue with `NULL` -- when you do set `end_datetime`, the record will have to be moved from one partition to another, thereby making the `UPDATE` statement somewhat costly.  (It is effectively a `DELETE` plus an `INSERT`.)  For this reason, I don't recommend Plan B for very high activity.

Comment: Cheers for the help Rick. The issue I have with partitioning by a datetime is what you acknowledged in your first point. Most of my queries ask for recent events, which means nearly all of the partitions are searched. This is making my performance worse than if I was to partition by location_id, and just index the datetimes. General query performance is of a higher importance to me than data purging ease. Because of this, do you think I should just be smarter about the way I delete and call it a day? For example, delete in smaller batch sizes?

Comment: @kezsto - (1) I think "Plan B" will significantly help your case about "recent events".  (2) The partitioning to speed up purging old data is an important part of Plan B.  Here is more on "big deletes": http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Comment: Ah of course, Plan B will definitely help. The only downfall in performance will be when querying large time ranges, which I don't plan to do often, and could probably use summary tables if needs be. So my only question remaining would be what happens to the records that are "current" and have a NULL end datetime? What partition will they be in? The MAXVALUE one?

Comment: Think I've just found it, it will go into the lowest partition, which is fine, I can deal with that. I think all of my options are at least clear now! Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah, I had not thought about `NULL`.  Yes, that should work -- but please see my added text.